# convert totaltime every time user login javascript

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

I want to get totalTime to be in readable format for every time user login but by this i only get time for id(1) ,for rest it shows in milliseconds.how can i do this.m using javascript +jsp+springmvc+hibernate

```
<%@page import=" com.ephesoft.timesheet.core.model.LoginLog"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01   Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function convertTime(milliSeconds) {

        var str, days, hours, minutes, seconds;

    if (milliSeconds > 0) {

        milliseconds = milliSeconds;
        days = Math.floor(milliseconds / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        if (days < 0) {
            days = 0;
        }
        milliseconds -= days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

        hours = Math.floor(milliseconds / (60 * 60 * 1000));
        if (hours < 0) {
            hours = 0;
        }
        milliseconds -= hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;

        minutes = Math.floor(milliseconds / (60 * 1000));

        if (minutes < 0) {
            minutes = 0;
        }
        milliseconds -= minutes * 60 * 1000;

        seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / (1000));
        if (seconds < 0) {
            seconds = 0;
        }

    } else {
        days = hours = minutes = seconds = 0;
    }

    str = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    return str;

    };
</script>
</head>

 <table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Login Id</td>
        <td>Login Time</td>
        <td>Logout Time</td>
        <td>Total Time(in Minutes)</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
      <--- changes for Date --->
    <%
        List<LoginLog> log = (List<LoginLog>)       r    equest.getAttribute("loginList");
      if(log != null) {
       for(LoginLog login : log) {
       String format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy  ",    Locale.ENGLISH).format(login.getLoginTime());


%>
<---    --->
    <tr>
    <td><%=login.getId()%></td>
    <td><%=login.getLoginTime()%></td>
    <td><%=login.getLogoutTime()%></td>




    <td id="a"><span id="time"><%=login.getTotalTime()%></span> <script>
                var milliSeconds =     document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;

                var c = convertTime(milliSeconds);
                document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = c;
            </script></td>

    </tr>
    <%
        }
        }
    %>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
can anyone please tell me appropriate way? THANKS.
```

Comment: @ Vivek was you able to fix the unique-id problem? working now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with this piece of code

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <td>Login Id</td>
      <td>Login Time</td>
      <td>Logout Time</td>
      <td>Total Time(in Minutes)</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>


<%
    List<LoginLog> log = (List<LoginLog>)request.getAttribute("loginList");
    if(log != null) {
       for(LoginLog login : log) {
%>
<tr>
<td><%=login.getId()%></td>
<td><%=login.getLoginTime()%></td>
<td><%=login.getLogoutTime()%></td>

<!-- changes --> 
<td id="a<%=login.getId()%>"><span id="time<%=login.getId()%>"><%=login.getTotalTime()%></span> <script>
            var milliSeconds =     document.getElementById("time<%=login.getId()%>").innerHTML;

            var c = convertTime(milliSeconds);
            document.getElementById("a<%=login.getId()%>").innerHTML = c;
        </script></td>

</tr>
<%
    }
 }
%>
</table>
```

You are creating several rows, and for all of them have th same id **"time"** then when you say in JS to

```
getElementById("id")
```

Will find the first occurences, thats why you always have the same date.

To make it work you should make your id unique, here is an option:

```
<span id="time<%login.getId()%>">
```

And later in your JS code

```
var milliSeconds =     document.getElementById("time"<%=login.getId()%>).innerHTML;
```

Comment: @Vivek sure i will edit my response. Are just few changes from your original code

Comment: when I debug it it shows me syntaxerror * missing ) after argument list * at this line  ** var milliSeconds =     document.getElementById("time"1).innerHTML; **.....

Comment: @Vivek my bad the syntax is not right, is this: var milliSeconds =     document.getElementById("time<%=login.getId()%>").innerHTML;

Comment: hii @cralfaro ,It update id(1) everytime instead update recored for new id.?

Comment: @Vivek i just updated my response, the problem was the same again but with the tag <td id="a"> remember that when you use Id's in tag elements those must to be uniques in your code, or when you run document.getElementById('id') you will get always the first occurence

Comment: can you please tell me one more thing? i need to get details of every user for a single date (like it will show me date only one time but by this code(m updating previous one) it gives me date for every record**I hope you'll get what m trying to say?

Comment: @Vivek nice, could you validate my response so if someone else have the same problem can use it? thanks!. Thinking your second question...

Comment: yeah!sure..my bad, I just forgot that! can you please help me in next question?

Comment: @Vivek about your question i think you have to modify the way you are creating the "loginList" attribute and return only one date by user, always is better add business logic into the service and not in the view, so try to modify that method and return a list with only one record by user/date

Comment: @cralfaro..As I m new to this i did'nt get you!..can you please elaborate?(or i need to share my service,dao and controller).Thank you:)

Comment: tell me your email and i can ask you by email, and dont make longer this chat here ;)

Comment: sure!..It is vivek.viveksaxena55@gmail.com